# how to make a threshold for predicted image from uNet

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I'am training uNet model for microscopic images , when predicting an image with code bellow

```
 image = cv2.imread(image_path)
mask = cv2.imread(mask)

img = image
image = cv2.resize(image, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH))
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
prediction = loaded_model.predict(image)

prediction = prediction[0]*255

prediction = cv2.medianBlur(prediction, 5)
prediction = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(prediction, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
```

The pixels in the predicted image are like this
[image]

and the adaptiveThreshold function won't accept the prediction because it's pixels value are float.
I can't make a threshold to make a binarization for that prediction, am I doing anything wrong ?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to convert your predicted values to 0 or 1 if `<0.5` or `>0.5`.
You can use `np.round`, for instance :

```
>>> x=np.array([0.1,0.8,0.2,0.3,0.6])
>>> np.round(x)

array([0., 1., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Comment: Not exactly , round will round only one number , I want for more. Also I hoping there is a more efficient way.